# VueJS - Vuex Assign data in a mutation

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm getting used to `Vuex` as I need to be able to have a store that I can easily access and update when another component is changed.

Currently, my `store` looks like the following:

```
import vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        users: {

            columns: [],
            model:   [],

        }
    },

    mutations: {
        fetchUsers: function(state) {
          axios.get(`/users?search_input=`)
            .then(function(response) {


            });
        }
    }

});
```

The `columns` and `model` is dynamically pulled down from an ajax request and my `Users` looks like the following:

```
<script>

  export default {

    mounted() {
      this.$store.commit('fetchUsers'); 
    },
    computed: {
        columns() {
            return this.$store.state.users.columns;
        }

        model() {
            return this.$store.state.users.model
        }
    },
  }

</script>
```

My problem is that the application needs to have data preloaded from Ajax. For example `columns` are set from an ajax request in `fetchUsers` and inside the `Users` I use `this.$store.commit('fetchUsers');` but is there an alternative way I can do that without using `commit` preferably inside the store itself?

Comment: Vuex [mutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html) **mutate** the state – this is where you make changes to the state itself – they are always synchronous. Vuex [actions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html) do _things_, such as network requests, to get data – they can be asynchronous. Once you dispatch an action you need to commit it via a mutation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the store u can load ur data asynchronously via actions then commit the changes using a mutation.

```
import vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    users: {
      columns: [],
      model:   [],
    }
  },

  actions: {
    fetchUsers: function( context ) {
      axios.get(`/users?search_input=`)
      .then( function( response ) {
        context.commit( "FETCHUSERS", {
          columns: response.columns,
          model: response.model
        });  
      });   
    }
  }
  mutations: {
    FETCHUSERS: function( state, payload ) {
      state.users.columns = payload.columns;
      state.users.model = payload.model;
    }
  }
});
```

Dispatch the action from the component

```
<script>
  export default {
    .....
    methods: {
      fetchUsers: function() {
       this.$store.dispatch( "fetchUsers" );
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Mutations must be synchronous: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html

You should move ajax request into `actions`, which can be async. You get data in the `action`, commit mutation giving received data as a payload, and mutation assigns a value to the state property.

Alternatively, you can make async request in component method, and assign a value to the store property directly: `this.$store.state.prop = value`

Comment: Is there any documentation with regards to the `actions` in vuex / vuejs -- I can't find any documentation with regards to this

Comment: I'd recommend to read through all docs page about mutations, and then proceed to actions: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html Mutations are designed to mutate data synchronously, and actions are designed to perform async tasks.

Comment: I have added the following: `actions { fetchUsers(context) { } }` Then inside my component I do: `this.$store.dispatch('fetchUsers');` but getting the error: `Unknown Mutation type: fetchUsers`